# Find Overlapping Dates Give Infinite Loop MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

Let's assume I have one table with given dates:

```
+-----------+-----------+----+
|StartDate  |EndDate    |ID  |
+-----------+-----------+----+
|2013-08-29 |2014-12-29 |1   |
|2013-08-29 |2013-09-31 |2   |
|2015-01-02 |2015-03-20 |3   |
+-----------+-----------+----+
```

I want to find the conflicting dates, so the code should give me 1 as the conflicting dates. When I write this code in MySQL, it enters an infinite loop, which I would appreciate a little help, because I cannot see why it does not work:

```
select t1.* from dates t1
inner join dates t2
on t2.StartDate > t1.StartDate
and t2.StartDate < t1.EndDate;
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by *conflict*?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be?:

```
select t1.*, t2.id as conflict_id
from dates t1
inner join dates t2
on t2.StartDate >= t1.StartDate
and t2.EndDate <= t1.EndDate
and t2.id != t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't enter an infinite loop.  It just takes a long, long time.  However, this might be a better route:

```
select d.*
from dates d
where exists (select 1
              from dates d2
              where d2.StartDate < d1.EndDate and
                    d2.EndDate > d1.StartDate
             );
```

And index on `dates(StartDate, EndDate)` might help the query.

Comment: Thank you, that is better than my own code. 

One more question (I forgot to ask in the text): Assume I have added one more column to above table, with name "Name" and rows A,A,B. I want this code (check if there is conflicting dates) to look only at rows with A, then check conflicting date with the rows B etc. So, there could be conflicting dates between A and B, but not conflicting dates in the A group. How can I modify the code? Thank you.

Comment: Actually, this was my real question but I forgot to ask :)

Comment: @gurluk . . . You should ask another question and include sample data and desired results.  Don't ask new questions in comments.