# MySQL Overlapping Date in Group

Tags: mysql, date, overlapping-matches

Sorry if this question is basic, I am learning MySQL.

Let's assume I have one table with names and given dates:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
|Name|StartDate  |EndDate    |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|A   |2013-08-29 |2014-12-29 |
|A   |2013-08-29 |2013-09-31 |
|B   |2015-01-02 |2015-03-20 |
|B   |2013-08-20 |2013-08-30 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like to find the elements (Name) which has conflicting (overlapping) dates. Here, A has conflicting dates, B does not have, and code should return A. The overlapping between A and B does not matter. Thank you.

Comment: you've already asked this today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737559/find-overlapping-dates-give-infinite-loop-mysql

Comment: @pala_ . . . It is a different question.  That question had no `name` separating the dates into different groups.

Comment: This is different question.

Comment: ah. i see the variation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you tell me how this is different. To me it looks like he wants to find the names with overlapping dates, and in the other question he wants to find the IDs.

Comment: @Mathemats . . . I think the `id`s are irrelevant in the other question.

Comment: In other question, I was reporting the `id`'s. Here I want to group by `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
select distinct name
from onetable t
where exists (select 1
              from onetable t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.startdate < t.enddate and
                    t2.enddate > t.startdate
             );
```

The answer is similar to the previous answer, with the addition of the `name` comparison in the `where` clause.

The index that you want for this query is on `table(name, startdate, enddate)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon!